# Xquery: Selecting n number of records at a time

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

I'm using XQUERY, I have 25000 records saved in Database, I want to select these records in chunks(1000), How do I get the records recursively?

Answer (score 1):

### Window queries

You could use the [tumbling window](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#ezCasVWmzGJi/4+RbQH3UZCarqA=) for this purpose, sadly it isn't supported by many XQuery engines yet.

---

For the following suggestions, you have to wrap the results into XML as XQuery only knows flat sequences, no nested ones.

### Building your own tumbling windows

You can build your own tumbling windows functions which could look like this one, it creates "window" elements containing `$count` "item" elements each:

```
declare function local:window($seq as item()*, $size as xs:integer) as item()* {
    for $i in 1 to xs:integer(fn:ceiling(count($seq) div $size))
  return
      element {"window"} {
          for $j in (($i - 1) * $size + 1) to $i*$size
          return 
              element {"item"} {$seq[$j]}
        }
};


local:window((2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14), 3)
```

### Splitting sequences for recursive windows

If you want to solve this problem recursively, you will need some split function which sadly isn't available in standard xquery. You could use `$n=1000`, work with the "head" elements and call your "worker function" recursively with the "tail".

```
declare function local:split($seq as item()*, $n as xs:integer) as element()* {
    (
        element {"head"} {
            for $i in subsequence($seq, 1, $n)
            return element {"item"} {$i}
        },
        element {"tail"} {
            for $i in subsequence($seq, $n+1)
            return element {"item"} {$i}
        }
    )
};

local:split((2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14), 3)
```

To access the tail elements as a sequence, use

```
local:split((2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14), 3)[2]//item/data()
```